# Does mobile app means a native app of a certain platform

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile

I am on a research and our panel cannot quite understand that I am developing a mobile app using html5.

Does mobile app means a native app of a certain platform (ios / android)?

If the app can be accessed in a browser, does that mean this is not a mobile app? are there any articles/journals/researches that prove my claim that html5 applications nowadays are being considered as a mobile app today?

Answer (score 1):

From my epx, native apps are basically apps written/developed on the specific device/platform
Eg: Native app for android would be using Java, while iOS would be Objective C,

while mobile-apps in this case are basically web-apps, which works cross platform.
HTML5 is unique in a sense that it is able to simulate certain functions or accessing device hardware without being developed in a native environment.

If you are accessing the app via a web-browser on you mobile phone, most-likely its a web-app. 
Most sites will have different layouts for different platform, for example when using your Desktop or Laptop, you will have a different view compared to using your Mobile Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Some points that I hope you find useful:

#### Can it be published on the App Store/Google Play?

Think it's safe to say, most people expect a mobile app to be found in them.

Note that, from personal experience, Apple has rejected apps that are just simple copies of webpages.

#### Common sentiment

It's not very useful if a journal says something that the general public does not agree. Ask around, ideally people that are the target segment/market of your app, see if they agree on the definition of an App.

#### Many popular Apps using HTML5

There are many Apps on the App Store/Google Play that uses HTML5 as it's main development language. Facebook is the most visible one, though they went back to native for UX/performance reasons. (See: http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/11/mark-zuckerberg-our-biggest-mistake-with-mobile-was-betting-too-much-on-html5/)

#### Phonegap

Is a quick way to get HTML5 apps "into" a native app. If you are already not using it.

All the best with your panel!

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Apps Are not always native apps. Mobile apps can be Native, Mobile-Web or Hybrid. The Mobile-Web which is basically written in HTML5, CSS and Javascript.

Native Mobile Apps are Specific to a platform or Operating System written in most of the time a particular language examples are writing an android apps in JAVA and an IOS app in Objective C.

While Hybrid Apps are combinations of Both Native and web sometimes puree mobile-web but wrapped in a native shell. They simply runs on a native widget more like a Browser. For android its uses WebView